# how to attach movieclips in a movieclip from main time line dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a game for kids. I've a movieClip called "picChange" and inside that movieClip, there is another movieClip called "picFrame" and inside that movieClip there are three movieClips called "HolderL1", "HolderL2", "HolderL3".  I use these 3 movieClips to attach movieClips(questions for game) from library.  I put movieClip inside movieClip to add some animation while it loads. I used following code:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<3; i++) {      
  var pic_mc:String = "picLeft" + ranque[i];  
  var que_mc_class:Class = getDefinitionByName(pic_mc) as Class;  
  q = new que_mc_class();  
  picChange.picFrame.this["HolderL"+(i+1)].addChild(q);  
}
```

In above code ranque is randomly generated numbers and q is a sprite.  It's not working in the final code. But it works if I write it separately like   `picChange.picFrame.HolderL1.addChild(q);` I'm not sure if this is the write way to do it. So if there's any easier way to do it please help me out and if anyone know how to use this["HolderL"+i] from mainTimeLine to attach a movieClip inside a movieClip.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't really be anything before your keyword "this" as it refers to the object that this code is within (in this case the main timeline). So, you can do either:

```
picChange.picFrame["HolderL"+(i+1)].addChild(q);
```

or

```
this.picChange.picFrame["HolderL"+(i+1)].addChild(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MovieClip( picChange.picFrame.getChildByName("HolderL"+(i+1)) ).addChild(q);
```